# How to implement role-based views securely in Angular2?

Tags: security, angular, authorization, roles

I want to implement an authorization mechanism (with JWT) in my Angular2 project so that there will be some routes or some components not available for the unauthorized users.

I know this can be achieved by checking the user's role from the token with an if statement. What I worried is that if the browser show the source files in client sites, isn't it possible that the user change these files and see these components without authorization? Is it secure to make any authorization related controls on the client-side?

I don't have too many knowledge on security so any information will be helpful.

Comment: If your server depends on your client application not being tempered with, you are doomed. Security has to be enforced on the server. On the client showing some things and hiding others is **only** for the convenience of the user but not for any kind of security.

Comment: If you still want this, you can use lazy loading and prevent on the server  certain lazy-loaded modules are delivered on client requests that don't match the required role.

Comment: yes @GünterZöchbauer is right. check server side that particular user is hitting api is he has access to that api if not give Unauthorized error and handle it on client side like. 401 Unauthorized error. and when u get this 401 error show user that you don't have permission to do that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer for example, I give the same view to administrators and the users to change some settings, but there are some settings which are restricted by the administrator. User should not be able to change these. If I checked the role of the user in a function of a component and not able to validate again on the server, will it be insecure?

Comment: As insecure as it can get. I can open the browser console and send a request to your server from there that updates this setting. That's quite simple to do.

Comment: Furthermore, if you don't check what the clients send to the server, it's probably also quite easy to take full control of your server.

Comment: We will secure the server as much as possible, I just wanted to know how much I can feel free on the client-side. Thank you very much for these helpful informations.

Comment: It's **never** secured to make authorization related control on client side. It's just a luxury (and good practice) not to display what a user won't have access to. But always implements your checks on the server.